# R Studio For Loop error. Searched high and low

Tags: r, for-loop, leaflet

I searched high and low to find the answer, and I cannot find anything related to it. Any help will be appreciated in explaining what has cause this error. Thanks in advance.

```
 tabledata3<-getSQL("SELECT LONGITUDE,LATITUDE,SESSION,asd FROM ABC")
leaflet(subzone) %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(data = tabledata1, lng = ~ LONGITUDE, lat = ~ LATITUDE, popup = ~ S_ID, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), icon = ~markerList["before"])%>%
  addMarkers(data = tabledata2, lng = ~ LONGITUDE, lat = ~ LATITUDE, popup = ~ S_ID, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), icon = ~markerList["after"])%>%
  for (i in tabledata3$SESSION){
  addPolylines(data = tabledata3, lng = ~LONGITUDE, lat = ~LATITUDE, group = ~asd , color = "black", weight = 10)
    }
```

Error:

```
Warning: Error in for: 4 arguments passed to 'for' which requires 3
```

Edited the statement, also did tried the full

```
    for(i in 1:nrow(tabledata3)){
method}
```

but to no vain.

Comment: What is the `%>%` doing at the end of the loop?  Also, I don't see that you are actually using the loop variable `i`...why even have a loop?

Comment: I removed the %>% and the same error is there. I need the loop to draw multiple seperated polylines. Else, all the coordinate will link together in 1 line.

Comment: Erm, Sorry but what are the 4 argument in the statement? isn't there only 3? int i, 1: and number of row in tabledata3.

Comment: Well, you are using `%>%` to pipe things forward, in this case the leaflet map object which gets passed from function to function and ends up in the loop. Hence, the error message. To solve your problem, you would need to do something like `map <- leaflet(subzone) %>% addMarkers(...) %>% ...` and then `for (i in 1:nrow(tabledata3)) { map <- addPolylines(map, data = tabledata3[i, ], ...) }` to successively add lines to the same map object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it worked when I put the loop around the whole leaflet function:

```
tabledata3<-getSQL("SELECT LONGITUDE,LATITUDE,SESSION,asd FROM ABC")

leaflet(subzone) %>%
      addTiles() %>% 
      addMarkers(data = tabledata1, lng = ~ LONGITUDE, lat = ~ LATITUDE, popup = ~ S_ID, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), icon = ~markerList["before"])%>%
      addMarkers(data = tabledata2, lng = ~ LONGITUDE, lat = ~ LATITUDE, popup = ~ S_ID, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), icon = ~markerList["after"])

for(i in 1:nrow(tabledata3)){
  session_i <- tabledata3$SESSION[i,]
  leaflet(subzone) %>%
  addPolylines(data = session_i, lng = ~LONGITUDE, lat = ~LATITUDE, group = ~asd , color = "black", weight = 10)
    }
```

Hope it works!